# Check sync committee participation percentage

Tags: beacon-chain, hex, sync-committee

Looking f.e. at slot [3645537](https://sepolia.beaconcha.in/slot/3645537) I would like to verify the percentage of sync committee participation.

I get the sync aggregate of a given slot by hitting my beacon node on the following URL:

```
${beaconNodeUrl}/eth/v2/beacon/blocks/${slot}
```

The result is the sync committee signer bits and aggregate signature, both as hex strings.

In the beacon chain explorer the participation % is shown. I don't get this info from the API response, but I'm trying to get it by converting the sync committee signer bits from a hex string to array of bytes.

F.e. for the given slot above the signer bits are returned as

```
0xfdf5dbebdef4d57febfbfb78e5ffff7ffefdefbfdfd33ff7efffd7f8aeee76ffddd7f7cf5eb7f6f9fcf7cadff65bfffbbd4ff7b79fdfeffffff5f7efffeefd7e
```

And I'd like to convert them to

```
10111111 10101111 11011011 11010111 01111011 00101111 10101011 11111110
11010111 11011111 11011111 00011110 10100111 11111111 11111111 11111110
01111111 10111111 11110111 11111101 11111011 11001011 11111100 11101111
11110111 11111111 11101011 00011111 01110101 01110111 01101110 11111111
10111011 11101011 11101111 11110011 01111010 11101101 01101111 10011111
00111111 11101111 01010011 11111011 01101111 11011010 11111111 11011111
10111101 11110010 11101111 11101101 11111001 11111011 11110111 11111111
11111111 10101111 11101111 11110111 11111111 01110111 10111111 01111110
```

as displayed in the beacon chain explorer.

But I'm having trouble with that. With my solution I'm getting this result:

```
11111101 11110101 11011011 11101011 11011110 11110100 11010101 01111111
11101011 11111011 11111011 01111000 11100101 11111111 11111111 01111111
11111110 11111101 11101111 10111111 11011111 11010011 00111111 11110111
11101111 11111111 11010111 11111000 10101110 11101110 01110110 11111111
11011101 11010111 11110111 11001111 01011110 10110111 11110110 11111001
11111100 11110111 11001010 11011111 11110110 01011011 11111111 11111011
10111101 01001111 11110111 10110111 10011111 11011111 11101111 11111111
11111111 11110101 11110111 11101111 11111111 11101110 11111101 01111110
```

You can see that the binary codes differ from what's in the beacon chain explorer.
This is my solution in JS:

```typescript
export function hexToBinary(hexString: string): number[] {
  // Remove the '0x' prefix
  const hex = hexString.slice(2)
  let binaryCodes: number[] = []

  for (let i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 2) {
    const byte = parseInt(hex.slice(i, i + 2), 16)
    const binaryString = byte.toString(2).padStart(8, '0')
    binaryCodes.push(parseInt(binaryString))
  }

  return binaryCodes
}
```

and the test:

```js
  describe.only('committee participation hex to binary', () => {
    it('test', () => {
      const result = hexToBinary(
        '0xfdf5dbebdef4d57febfbfb78e5ffff7ffefdefbfdfd33ff7efffd7f8aeee76ffddd7f7cf5eb7f6f9fcf7cadff65bfffbbd4ff7b79fdfeffffff5f7efffeefd7e',
      )
      console.log(result)
    })
  })
```

And furthermore, how is the participation % calculated afterwards?